# Rest api implementation with parameter using JetBrains WebStorm + node.js + express

Tags: node.js, rest, express

First of all, i'm using JetBrains WebStorm and used to create the **Node.js Express App** project.

My modifications were at **app.js**

```
app.get('/api/restaurants', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Parameter[0]", req.params.restaurant_id);
  res.json({
    '01010112D8139F13': '0ao123r1'
  });
});
app.get('/api/restaurants/:id', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Parameter[1]", req.params.restaurant_id);
  res.json({
    'message': 'worked?'
  });
});
```

I'm using postman plugin at chrome to test my api and i can't access localhost:3000/api/restaurants?restaurant_id=01010112D8139F13 without being routed by router.route('/restaurants') instead of router.route('/restaurants/:restaurant_id')

At console i have:

```
GET /api/restaurants?id=01010112D8139F13 200 1.803 ms - 31
```

If anyone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having a specific error? And please, don't include your code as screenshots. Include the code in the question itself instead. Be sure to stop by the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information on how to use the site. In particular, review the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Welcome to Stack Overflow, and happy asking!

Comment: No errors, it is just handled by router.route('/restaurants')

At log i recieve GET /api/restaurants/?restaurant_id=01010112D8139F13 200 1.803 ms - 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restaurant_id is not a query parameter but a variable part in your path. For example `/restaurants/01010112` and `/restaurants/1` are both handled by the same Web request handler because both fit on `/restaurants/:restaurant_id` pattern.

The restaurant specific endpoint need to be modified the following way:

```
app.get('/api/restaurants/:id', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Parameter[1]", req.params.id);
  res.json({
    'message': 'worked?'
  });
});
```

And use the following url on the console:

`/api/restaurants/01010112D8139F13`